# Certbot gives an error for apache2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-virtualhost

I tried to configure SSL using this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-22-04

But I get this error:

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$ sudo certbot --apache
[sudo] password for serv_ivan: 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
```

---

```
1: vardidze.ru
2: www.vardidze.ru
```

---

```
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 
Requesting a certificate for vardidze.ru and www.vardidze.ru

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate       Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: vardidze.ru
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 94.228.120.106: Invalid response from http://vardidze.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/3_vZwseS0tgfCsIJYvlU91atg-lEkdzvQZ58W-rJH98: 403

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

Although my domain is available: [www.vardidze.ru](http://www.vardidze.ru)

Help me please.

Comment: Does your webserver answer to the name `vardidze.ru` or only to the name `www.vardidze.ru`?

Comment: Answers to both options

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have selected "manual mode" to request a certificate from LetsEncrypt's `Certbot` software, and indicated you want to prove your ownership of the domain name via the `http` challenge, as described in the first four paragraphs of the "Manual" section of [this Certbot documentation page](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#manual)

The http challenge requires the owner of the web server put a file on the web server for Certbot to retrieve.  The name and contents of the file are given by Certbot, and are unique to the request for the SSL certificate.  If Certbot can retrieve the contents of the file, it proves that you own the web server and are entitled to receive the certificate.

When Certbot tried to retrieve the file from your web server, it received a 403 error.  Add the file and its contents to your web server and ask Certbot to try again.  Or, if you would rather use the `dns` challenge (you add a TXT record to your DNS for `vardidze.ru`), indicate this to Certbot with the command-line option mentioned in the documentation page earlier in this answer.